# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a valid json that I'm unable to read using Python and getting the error,

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded using Python
```

The code is as following,

```
import json, requests

page = "http://www.zillow.com/search/GetResults.htm?spt=homes&status=110001&lt=001000&ht=111111&pr=,&mp=,&bd=2%2C&ba=0%2C&sf=,&lot=,&yr=,&pho=0&pets=0&parking=0&laundry=0&income-restricted=0&pnd=0&red=0&zso=0&days=any&ds=all&pmf=1&pf=1&zoom=3&rect=-134340820,16594081,-56469727,54952386&p=1&sort=globalrelevanceex&search=maplist&disp=1&listright=true&isMapSearch=true&zoom=3"
response = requests.get(page) # request the json file
json_response =  json.loads(response.text) # parse the json file
```

When I open the URL in the browser, I was able to see the JSON file properly and can validate using the website: `http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer`. What's the issue here ?

When I use print `response.text`, I get the following output:

```
u'<html><head><title>Zillow: Real Estate, Apartments, Mortgage &amp; Home Values in the US</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400&subset=latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/9520695/static/css/z-pages/captcha.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/><script language="javascript">\n            function onReCaptchaLoad() {\n                window.reCaptchaLoaded = true;\n            }\n\n            window.setTimeout(function () {\n                if (!window.reCaptchaLoaded) {\n                   document.getElementById(\'norecaptcha\').value = true;\n                   document.getElementById(\'captcha-form\').submit();\n                }\n            }, 5000);\n        </script></head><body><main class="zsg-layout-content"><div class="error-content-block"><div class="error-text-content"><!-- <h1>Captcha</h1> --><h5>Enter the characters in the images to continue.</h5><div id="content" class="captcha-container"><form method="POST" action="" id="captcha-form"><script type="text/javascript">\r\nvar RecaptchaOptions = {"theme":"white","lang":"en-US"};\r\n</script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Lf2nvMSAAAAAMQ5p6WlAfDEixMdOQgJsij-3_ud" onload="onReCaptchaLoad()"></script>\r\n<br/><input id="dest" name="dest" type="hidden" value="ognl:originalDestination"/><input id="norecaptcha" name="norecaptcha" type="hidden" value="false"/><button type="submit" class="zsg-button zsg-button_primary">Submit</button></form><img src="http://www.zillowstatic.com/static/logos/logo-65x14.png" width="65" alt="Zillow" height="14"></img></div></div></div></main></body></html><!-- H:049  T:0ms  S:1494  R:Thu May 26 23:12:41 PDT 2016  B:5.0.29554-release_20160512-lunar_lander.6d4c099~candidate.d23c8e0 -->'
```

So, it seems that I'm not getting JSOn from the server, while, the link open is JSON in the browser (Chrome)

Comment: what version of python are you using? the code seems to run fine, i copy pasted your snippet and get a valid json when i print(json_response)

Comment: `Python 2.7.9` is the version

Comment: That code is working for me on v2.7. It could be that you have an error in getting the response text. Try `print(response.text)` and check if you have a json response from the sever.

Comment: So, I don't get the JSON from the server, only HTML

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: No IDE, Mac OS terminal , just start writing `python` there to open the shell and you know what ? the same code works few minutes earlier :D

Comment: @Arefe can you post the output of `print(response.text)` in the question ?

Comment: Yes, I provided that in the bottom part of the answer.

Comment: Just tested on MAC it works.  what version of requests are you using? Close mac terminal, open another and try it.. MACs have weird behavior of caching programs... check to make sure that terminal is closed

Comment: requests.__version__ mine :'2.7.0'

Comment: It seems like you have hit this website HARD. The above html is a RECAPTACHA

Comment: Okay, what should I do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using requests as a lib, you can do the following:

```
import requests as req

page = "http://www.zillow.com/search/GetResults.htm?spt=homes&status=110001&lt=001000&ht=111111&pr=,&mp=,&bd=2%2C&ba=0%2C&sf=,&lot=,&yr=,&pho=0&pets=0&parking=0&laundry=0&income-restricted=0&pnd=0&red=0&zso=0&days=any&ds=all&pmf=1&pf=1&zoom=3&rect=-134340820,16594081,-56469727,54952386&p=1&sort=globalrelevanceex&search=maplist&disp=1&listright=true&isMapSearch=true&zoom=3"

json_response = req.get(page).json()

print type(json_response)

>> <type 'dict'>
```

Here you go !

EDIT:  Death-Stalker is right, you hit the website too many times, this is why you're not getting the page you request, but the code is fine, what I showed is way of simplifying it. Unless you use another IP address to query the website, I can't see a solution.

Comment: The same as before `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` I believe I worked on the website little long and the site is tracking it.